# Check if an input text field has a specific numeric value and change the selected option of a select using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select menu with 3 options and i want to have the 3d option selected on page load when the input text fields has value 0 (zero) and 2nd option selected when the input text field is empty. Here is my code:

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#price').val('0')) {
$('#pricetypeselect').val()=='3';
} else if ($('#price').val('')) {
$('#pricetypeselect').val()=='2';
}
});*/

//HERE IS THE WORKING CODE BASED ON THE SELECTED ANSWER BELOW
$(document).ready(function() { 
$select = $('#pricetypeselect');
$priceVal = $('#price').val();

if($priceVal=='0'){
   $select.val('3')
}else if($priceVal==''){
    $select.val('2')
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <select id="pricetypeselect">
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
 </select>
 
 <input id="price" type="text" name="price" value="0" placeholder="price in USD $"/>
```

What i 'm doing wrong ?

Comment: val()=='3' is wrong. You should do val('3');

Comment: your `ifs`  are also wrong. It evalueates to value... If it valuates to value diffrent than 0 then it always returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $select = $('#pricetypeselect');
    $priceVal = $('#price').val();

    if($priceVal=='0'){
       $select.val('3')
    }else if($priceVal==''){
        $select.val('2')
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Junaed Siam. I will select your answer as the worked one ;)